# my dogs eats sandals and plastics

Tags: dogs

My dog is a cross of Japanese Spitz and Labrador. She is well behaved but bad in some points as she eats parts of shoes and some times plastic bags. I sometimes  feel to hit her with stick but  she is like my sister. Do you have any ways in which I should not hit her and she will be ok?

Answer (score 4):

Firstly you should under no circumstances hit your dog, especially not with a stick - this in most countries will loose you your dog.

Secondly - just treat train her the 'Leave it' command. My own dog is a huge fan of flip flops and socks. However if your dog knows the 'Leave it' command then you can apply this to any object.

First take a small treat, in your hand, palm facing upwards. Tell your dog to 'Leave it' - if she tries to eat it then close your hand. If she leaves it for 3 seconds - tell her to 'Take it'. Repeat this until she doesn't even move towards the treat until you tell her to do so. Once you're at that stage, make the gap in time longer and longer. This is a basic 'Leave it'.

You can then begin applying the logic to your shoes and plastic bags - or any other object of issue (like for our dog: poo, socks, gloves). When your dog goes near an object you don't want them to chew on - say 'Leave it' and if they do, reward them with a treat. If they don't simply take the object away. Again, repetition is the key with dogs.

If your dog is chewing when you are not around, then don't leave these kind of items in her vicinity when on her own.